# React-leaflet-sidetab not compatible with new version of React (v18.2.0)

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, react-18

I'm very new in React and I'm trying to do a project whose main topic is a map and I want to use a sidetab. I found some very nice examples online and I use them outside of my project to test them out and they worked.

However when I tried to implement them in my project I had some dependency errors when installing the library, and that's because it's not compatible with the new version of React that I use in my project.

Do you have any alternatives to suggest?

Comment: Could you share the errors?

Comment: npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-leaflet-sidetabs@1.0.1   
npm ERR! node_modules/react-leaflet-sidetabs
npm ERR!   react-leaflet-sidetabs@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

Comment: The above error is when I use the "npm install react-leaflet-sidetabs"